# How to get data in new array, but not all (Java)

Tags: java

I've got array like this

```
int[] array = {5, 100, 20, 66, 16};
    price = new int[] {5, 100, 20, 66, 16};
    for(int i = offset; i < price[price.length - readLength]; i++) {
        price[i] = price[i] * (discount / 100);
        System.out.println(price[i]);

    }
```

I need to get new array after this only with three numbers of the old array. How can I do it? I need after that something like this [100,20,66]

Comment: which three numbers?  Any of them?

Comment: it seems strange that you are comparing indexes to prices ( i < price[whatever] )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) to get this:

`price = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, 4)` and then you can do operations on each element.

Or you could get a new array from the original array using:

```
double[] discounted_price = 
    Arrays.stream(array,1,4).
                  mapToDouble(el ->el - el*(discount/100.0)).toArray();
```

You don't need to use a copy to pass to stream, you can specify, `from, to` in [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-int-int-) itself.

And @WJS is correct that you might need to subtract price*discount from price depending on how you intend to use discount.

Comment: And how can I apply discount(in %) to this numbers in array?

Comment: @CogsMaster  Did you see my answer?

Comment: IMHO a non functional solution would be clearer to an OP asking at this level. But I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has some problems.

- The following won't work unless price has been declared an array and it should be a double array since you probably want the result to be a floating point number.

```
   double[] price = new double[3];
```

- This will be a problem unless discount is a double or float. Also, consider that if something costs $2 and the discount is 10% then the cost will be:  `2.00 - (2.00 * .10)`.
  So you should change:

```
   price[i] = price[i] * (discount/100);
```

To

```
   price[i] = price[i] - (price[i] * (discount/100.));
```

To copy array you can either use a for loop or the `Arrays.copyOfRange() method` as already mentioned.  If you want random values you have to do individual assignments.  The for loop would look like:

```
int k = 0 ;
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) { // copies values at indices 1,2, and 3
  price[k++] = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange()
```

Comment: Helpful, but not detailed at all. Please show a full solution with explanation and possibly also links to the documentation. Read [answer]. Your answer is low-quality.